# Google Apps Script range getValues returns null if any cell contains a date

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the range values. I noticed, if any range cell contains a date value (for example, 2000-01-01), *getValues()* returns **null**:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MY_NAMED_RANGE').getValues();
```

But when using *getDisplayValues()* I get the values no problem

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MY_NAMED_RANGE').getDisplayValues();
```

Is it a bug of *getValues()*?
I need to get the precise/unformatted values, so I cannot use *getDisplayValues()*

Thanks in advance for your help!

---

Thank you all for your replies. I'm trying to get some named range data in my Google Sheets custom sidebar, here is my simplified example:

So I use this (backend) Google Script function (getting the values of a named range):

```
function gsExplorationData(){
    var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MyNamedRange');
    Logger.log({'range.getValues()': range.getValues()});
    return {'range.getValues()': range.getValues()}
}
```

Here is my Sidebar javascript function:

```
dataSubmit(){
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(error){console.log('GS ERROR: '+ error.message)}).withSuccessHandler(function(gsResponse){
    console.log('gsExplorationData()',gsResponse);
  }).gsGetgsExplorationDataData()
}
```

When running ***dataSubmit()*** I see the results fine in the Executions logs:
[cloud logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqXJF.png)

BUT the ***dataSubmit()*** outputs null in the DEV tools:
[getting Null in the sidebar javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6rso.png)

Now if I simply remove the date value in Cell B16 from my named range, I get the range values in the sidebar javascript function no problem:
[no date values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CiXn.png)

Or if change my google script function to return getDisplayValue(), it also works:

```
function gsExplorationData(){
    var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MyNamedRange');
    Logger.log({'range.getValues()': range.getValues()});
    return {'range.getDisplayValues()': range.getDisplayValues()}
}
```

[getDisplayValues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn4B5.png)

It also works if I stringify getValues:

```
function gsExplorationData(){
    var range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MyNamedRange');
    Logger.log({'range.getValues()': range.getValues()});
    return {'range.getValues() stringified': JSON.stringify(range.getValues())}
}
```

[stringified values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSWCH.png)

So the issue is with getting the range getValues() results (that contain date values) from a Google Sheets function in a sidebar javascript function.

UPDATE: kudos to @Daniel who pointed out to the limitations of Apps Script, in particular when returning Dates from Google Script functions called using google.script.run

> This has been reported in Google's issue tracker in the past, but it
> has been marked as "Intended behavior", so it seems that there are no
> plans to add this functionality at the moment. It could be a limit of
> how the Apps Script client-to-server communication works, or some kind
> of security measure.
>
> As a workaround you can try to pass the dates as raw strings, and then
> convert them to Date objects on the client-side.
>
> Reference: HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions

Comment: When I tested `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('MY_NAMED_RANGE').getValues();` including the date object, I can confirm that the date object can be seen. Unfortunately, I cannot correctly replicate your current issue of `I noticed, if any range cell contains a date value (for example, 2000-01-01), getValues() returns null:`. I apologize for my poor skill. In order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it?

Comment: Are you displaying the values in a html sidebar or dialog?

Comment: Hi. Would you please provide some sample data (as text), define your named range, include a logger statement to show the values in each approach, and generally create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you trying to read the data? Like the other comments, I was also unable to reproduce the issue. `getValues()` works fine at retrieving dates. It's also odd that you're getting `null` since even blank cells will be returned as blank strings instead of null values.

Answer (score 1):

I checked your sample code, and this is a limitation of trying to pass the values to the sidebar with `google.script.run`. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values):

> Legal parameters and return values are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, as well as JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects and arrays.
>
> (...)
>
> **Requests fail if you attempt to pass a Date, Function, DOM element besides a form,** or other prohibited type, including prohibited types inside objects or arrays.

This has been reported in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140447157) in the past, but it has been marked as "Intended behavior", so it seems that there are no plans to add this functionality at the moment. It could be a limit of how the Apps Script client-to-server communication works, or some kind of security measure.

As a workaround you can try to pass the dates as raw strings, and then convert them to `Date` objects on the client-side.

##### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Many thanks @Daniel!!! I couldn't find it myself and honestly I would never suspect anything like that about Dates. My solution would be to stringify the data before returning it to the sidebar.